# How do I transfer my ePub files from my Mac to iPhone 5s?

Tags: ios, macos, epub

I'm trying to read the epub files that I bought from gumroad, and I cannot figure out how to transfer it to my iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Dropbox on your Mac and Dropbox on your phone (and assuming you have iBooks on your phone), you can open the epub files in Dropbox on your phone. Although you will get a message "Unable to view file", if you tap the Download icon on the top right, it will give you the option to Open in iBooks.

Answer (score 1):

I manage my books using iTunes on my Mac and have not found any issues with gumroad texts and using Apple's iBooks reader.